# Azure MobileServiceInvalidOperation Exception has been thrown

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin

I am working with the `xamarin.forms` app generated when you download the sample for working with Azure Mobile Services. I have made some modifications. Firstly, I have changed Todo, to entry.cs:

```
public class entry
{
    string id;

    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Time")]
    public int Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Percentage")]
    public int Percentage { get; set; }

    //I have omitted Device, Replacement, Use_profile, Longitude, Latitude, Battery
}
```

I try to add a new line to the table in my SQL database, by calling the following code from my page in cs:

```
var data = new entry{ Longitude = await GetLongitude(), Latitude = await GetLatitude(), Percentage = bpm }; // initialise new data entry 
await AddItem (data);
```

When this is called, the app crashes.
Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/e224d992ebe52b0420cb) of the log when the exception is thrown. It gives a `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOpperationException has been thrown`

Explanation:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had it's name changed, or is temporarily unavailable`

This is thrown on the `UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");` line in main.cs under the ios project.

Any thoughts on why this is happening would be much appreciated.

## UPDATE:

Just to add a little more info, I have a web service setup at `http://project.azurewebsites.net`  this is the address referenced in the constants section of the mobile application I am building in xamarin. However, the SQL database is at `http://project-db.database.windows.net` how do I get around this? Can I create a database on the original domain, or change the reference in the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are getting a 404 error when you are calling your Mobile Backend. You need to add a new Table Controller to handle the "entry" class, because your client will be trying to post to https://yourservice.azurewebsites.net/tables/entry, which doesn't exist.

In your server project, you need to add a new class Entry that inherits from EntityData. Then you add this type to your DbContext class and add a table controller. This tutorial for [Mobile Services controllers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn614132.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) might be helpful. If you're using Mobile Apps, you would use Add -> New Scaffolded Item -> Azure Mobile Apps -> Mobile Apps Table Controller.

Then, deploy your server project so that the new REST endpoint is available and then your client app should be able to connect.

Edited to add: you specify the connect to the SQL Database in the MS_TableConnectionString setting in web.config. Whatever value is the Connection Strings section of the Azure Portal will override this. For more information, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/.

Comment: Thanks, which file in the standard Todo Azure app, acts as the Table Controller? Visual Studio doesn't seem to have the scaffold items template referenced in that tutorial.

Comment: Make sure you installed the latest version of the Azure SDK. In the quickstart server project, there is one TableController called TodoItemsController. This is all based on ASP.NET WebAPI, so if you're familiar with that, it follows a very similar pattern.

Comment: Hmmm, still struggling. I am working with Xamarin.forms (PCL), and as such have ended up building a web app, rather than a mobile service, as per [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-xamarin-forms-get-started-preview/) tutorial, can this still work?

Comment: Yes, that's actually an App Service Mobile App, which is the next version of Mobile Services.